# ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry even after collectstatic

Tags: django

I'm getting server errors because django can't find one of my static files even though I can see it in the folder:

`ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'staticfiles\assets\img\icons\theme\communication\adress-book-2.svg'`

I see the file sitting in this folder right here in both static and staticfiles:

`static\assets\img\icons\theme\communication\`
[image: file path]

[image]

file path in template:

```
{% load static %}
              <img src="{% static 'assets\img\icons\theme\communication\adress-book-2.svg' %}" alt="Confirmation Icon" class="icon bg-primary" data-inject-svg="data-inject-svg">
```

Running `collectstatic` doesn't have any effect. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Forgot to add settings.py static settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Do other static files in that directory work ?

Comment: yes. I don't see any other crashes. Although what's interesting is that when I inspect source, it looks like some of the images are being loaded from /static/ and not /staticfiles/

Comment: Why do you have 2 static file directories ?

Comment: honestly, I don't know. I'm new to django and pushing deployments to heroku. I read up on loading static files and when I ran collect static it created a second folder, probably based on my settings.py. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: just noticed I also have `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` in my installed apps setting

Comment: The second folder was created because of your settings.py

Comment: figured. how should I proceed? What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the lines that say :

```
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

And then you can keep the first 2 lines:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Folder') #either put static or staticfiles and then remove the other folder
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: thanks for the help so far. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error `Missing staticfiles manifest entry`

Comment: if I attempt to run staticfiles command, it says it will collect static files at destination specified in settings to staticfiles, doesn't say static even though I changed those settings

Comment: If you run the command does it still create a new  folder ?

Comment: yes. I didn't actually delete the folder, but the command says 0 static files copied to staticfiles

Comment: could it be because of `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` in installed apps?

Comment: Is there anywhere in your settings file where it says staticfiles ?

Comment: just installed apps and `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'`

Comment: Try and remove the second one it might help

Comment: it created staticfiles again

Comment: What if you run the server without collectstatic ?

Comment: if I delete staticfiles and don't run collect static, none of the pages load as it seems to be looking in that folder for everything

Comment: Then why not just change all the references to staticfiles instead of static ?

Comment: just tried it, now the css isn't even loading. strange

Comment: Try Shift + F5 to clean reload resources

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help :/